# Log::Log4Perl screen logger stops working after creating a file logger

Tags: perl, file, logging, screen, log4perl

I have a Perl program in which I have to have one set of messages go to the screen (stdout) and another set go to a file.  I create two loggers for each of those outputs: the screen logger first, then the file logger. When I create the screen logger and use it, messages do appear on the screen.  After I create the file logger, messages printed using the screen logger no longer appear on the screen.  When using the file logger, however, messages do appear in the file.

The Log::Log4Perl configurations for the loggers are as follows:

```
# Screen configuration:
my $screen_conf = q(
log4perl.logger.MyPackage                           = DEBUG, Screen
log4perl.appender.Screen                            = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.Screen.stderr                     = 1
log4perl.appender.Screen.mode                       = append
log4perl.appender.Screen.layout                     = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.Screen.layout.ConversionPattern   = %d %5p> %m%n
);

Log::Log4perl->init( \$screen_conf );
$screen_logger = Log::Log4perl::get_logger( 'MyPackage' );

# Messages do appear on the screen:
$screen_logger->debug('Some more test text');

# File configuration:
my $file_conf = q(
log4perl.logger.MyPackage                          = DEBUG, LogFile
log4perl.appender.LogFile                          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.LogFile.filename                 = mylogfile.log
log4perl.appender.LOG.mode                         = append
log4perl.appender.LogFile.layout                   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.LogFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %5p> %m%n
);

Log::Log4perl->init( \$file_conf );
$sfile_logger = Log::Log4perl::get_logger( 'MyPackage' );

# Messages do not appear on the screen now:
$screen_logger->debug('Some more test text');

# Messages do appear in the file:
$screen_logger->debug('Some more test text');
```

I have traced thru the code, checked return values, and still have not found what the problem could be.  Suggestions as to what the problem might be caused by (or an answer, at this point) would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

==================================================================

Environment information:  I am using Perl v5.16.3 on Windows 7 and 8.  Directives and includes are as follows:

```
#****************************************************************************;
# Compiler directives
#****************************************************************************;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

#****************************************************************************;
# Module includes
#****************************************************************************;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;
use File::Basename qw( fileparse fileparse_set_fstype );
use File::Spec;
use Getopt::Long;
use Log::Log4perl;
use Readonly;
use Time::Piece;
use version;
```

Comment: Why the 2 separate logger objects?  Do you always want the same message going to both places?

Comment: The short answers to having two loggers is, one, that the customer wants mesages thru the program logged differently, and, two, the customer doesn't want to install modules such as ones for, say, adding appenders later in the program flow.  The shortest answer would be that it's what the customer wants.

Comment: I've tried with stderr = 0 and 1 with the same result; apologies for not including that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second call to `init` overrides the first call.

Declare both configurations in the same variable with different logger names:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Log::Log4perl qw(get_logger);

my $conf = q(
log4perl.logger.MyPackage                           = DEBUG, Screen
log4perl.appender.Screen                            = Log::Log4perl::Appender::Screen
log4perl.appender.Screen.stderr                     = 1
log4perl.appender.Screen.mode                       = append
log4perl.appender.Screen.layout                     = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.Screen.layout.ConversionPattern   = %d %5p> %m%n

log4perl.logger.MyPackagef                         = DEBUG, LogFile
log4perl.appender.LogFile                          = Log::Log4perl::Appender::File
log4perl.appender.LogFile.filename                 = mylogfile.log
log4perl.appender.LOG.mode                         = append
log4perl.appender.LogFile.layout                   = Log::Log4perl::Layout::PatternLayout
log4perl.appender.LogFile.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %5p> %m%n
);

Log::Log4perl->init( \$conf );
my $screen_logger = Log::Log4perl::get_logger( 'MyPackage' );

# Messages do appear on the screen:
$screen_logger->debug('Some more test text');

my $sfile_logger = Log::Log4perl::get_logger( 'MyPackagef' );

# Messages do appear on the screen now:
$screen_logger->debug('Some more test text 2');

# Messages do appear in the file:
$sfile_logger->debug('Some more test text file');
```

Comment: Hmmm, I made a mistake on the write-up: the logging configurations are actually different (scoped using "my" in different subroutines). The stdout logger is initialized in one subroutine, the file logger in the other.

Comment: On the off-change that a reference is being kept somewhere that I didn't track, I'll try it... thanks.

Comment: That'll work --- thanks.  Reading this more carefully in the docs would have helped me as well: "Initialize once and only once - 
It's important to realize that Log::Log4perl gets initialized once and only once, typically at the start of a program or system. Calling init() more than once will cause it to clobber the existing configuration and replace it by the new one."